# How Can I Refactor into One API Call to make multiple mySQL queries?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs

I currently have the below code that works. It makes 8 API calls in order to create a row and insert data into 8 different tables.  I would like to refactor it to 1 API call, which makes all the necessary queries at one time.

The only difference in each fetch below is the table name.

```
createQuestions() {
    fetch(
      API_URL + `/interview/create/questions/${this.state.lastEmployeeId}`,
      {
        method: "PUT",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          lastEmployeeId: this.state.lastEmployeeId,
          table: "audit_general",
        }),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      }
    )
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error();
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      .then(
        fetch(
          API_URL + `/interview/create/questions/${this.state.lastEmployeeId}`,
          {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify({
              lastEmployeeId: this.state.lastEmployeeId,
              table: "audit_culture",
            }),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          }
        )
          .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
              throw new Error();
            }
            return res.json();
          })
          .then((data) => console.log(data))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      )
      .then(
        fetch(
          API_URL + `/interview/create/questions/${this.state.lastEmployeeId}`,
          {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify({
              lastEmployeeId: this.state.lastEmployeeId,
              table: "audit_performance",
            }),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          }
        )
          .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
              throw new Error();
            }
            return res.json();
          })
          .then((data) => console.log(data))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      )
      .then( etc, etc, etc,
```

I suppose instead, I should be able to run multiple queries through this route with just one call instead?

```
app.put("/interview/create", function (req, res) {
  const employee = req.body.employee;
  const employment_level = req.body.employment_level;
  const audit_id = req.body.audit_id;
  console.log(`employee: ${employee}`);
  console.log(`employment_level: ${employment_level}`);
  console.log(`audit_id: ${audit_id}`);
  connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    connection.query(
      `INSERT INTO audit_interview (employee, employment_level, audit_id)
                VALUES (?, ?, ?)`,
      [employee, employment_level, audit_id],
      function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.json(results);
        console.log(`Interview has been created`);
        connection.release();
      }
    );
  });
});
```

My main problem is that this works locally fine.  But online in my production environment, I keep getting 502 and 503 calls, which seem to be caused by too many calls too close together.  I thought maybe reducing my calls as much as possible would be a good thing anyway.

Comment: You don't need to make assumptions about `which seem to be caused by too many calls too close together`. Please, look at the logs and confirm what are the server errors.